# Doubt on the convergence of this series (looks like a very hard and interesting issue).

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I would like to know if the series $\displaystyle 2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |k|^{-r} \cos(kx)$ or $\displaystyle \sum_{k\neq 0} |k|^{-r} e^{ikx}$ (actually they are the same) is convergent, where $0<r<1$, $x\in (-\pi,\pi)$ (one dimension).
Let us ignore the point $x=0$. Since if $x=0$, this series is divergent immediately so we do not need to consider the original seires anymore.

The answer is yes but I do not know why. Could you tell me which page of the book should I find on this knowledge?

Comment: Perhaps you should only use the comparison criteria. once $\cos(kx)$ or $e^{ikx}$ has modulus less than or equal to 1 and the remaining series is convergent.

Comment: But please note that, after you do the estimate, the rest of the series is divergent, not convergent. That is, $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{|k|^r}$ is divergent when $r\leq 1$.

Comment: Look up Dirichlet's test for series.

Comment: For Dirichlet's test, how to get the bound ${\displaystyle \left|\sum _{k=1}^{N}\cos(kx)\right|\leq M}$ for every positive integer $N$?

Comment: Even though we have the formula $$  \cos x+\cos 2x+\cos 3x+\cdots+ \cos nx=\frac{\sin (\frac {nx}2)    \cos \frac {(n+1)x}2 }{\sin (\frac x2)},       $$ we can not control $\sin (\frac x2)$ in the bottom.

Comment: @Latex2e Yes you can -- $x$ is fixed, so the denominator is fixed. You want pointwise convergence of the series, don't you?

Comment: @ Clement. So if I get convergence for pointwise, can I say for any $x\in (-\pi,\pi)$ it is convergent?

Comment: @ClementC. But at least, you can not take $x=0$ in to that series since the result is immediately divergent.

Comment: @Latex2e Yes, because your formula above of the sum of $\cos kx$ doesn't really work well when $x=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following things are true:

Let $f(x)$~$\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k^{-r} \cos(kx), 0<r<1, x \in [-\pi,\pi]$

Then as $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k^{-r} \cos(kx)$ converges uniformly on any compact set in $[-\pi, \pi]$ that doesn't contain $0$ (or more generally doesn't contain $2k\pi$ if we extend to the real axis by periodicity), $f$ is continuos except at $0$ (or more generally $2k\pi$).

Since $f(x)=(\Gamma(1-r) \sin\frac{\pi r}{2})x^{r-1}+O(1), 0<r<1$ when $0 <x \le \pi$ and $f$ is even, $f \in L^1[-\pi,\pi]$ and $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k^{-r} \cos(kx)$ is its Fourier series

The first claim follows from the usual Dirichlet kernel and summation by parts since $\frac{1}{\sin \frac{x}{2}}$ is uniformly bounded on compact sets in $[-\pi,\pi]$ that do not contain $0$

The second statement is trickier but it follows from the expansion of $\frac{1}{(1-z)^r}$ on $|z|=r<1$ using the usual Binomial formula , estimates for said Binomial coefficients and then taking the limit $r \to 1$ and separating real and imaginary parts (which gives a similar formula for the corresponding $\sin$ series)

Comment: This is the essential answer to this problem. This problem looks easy, but actually, it does not. An implicit and deep meaning has been expressed in this answer very clearly.